# Theming image.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming, media

What name do I have to give to my image.html.twig so the template only being used in content type "project" because I need to add class to an `<img>` tag.
I already tried

- image--node--field-afbeeldingen--project.html.twig
- image--node--field-afbeeldingen.html.twig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about overriding the `<img>` tag itself, but for your approach I would recommend overriding the field template. Assuming your field is named `field_afbeeldingen`, you can create a template called `field--field-afbeeldingen.html.twig`.

Within there, you could manually render your `<img>` tag as needed, with whatever additional classes required.